# Looking for an SQL query that does an ORDER BY first and then a GROUP BY

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a single table (called people) that includes among others: *ID, code, FullName, ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2, ADDRESS3, COUNTRY* and *IsMember*. The *ID* and *IsMember* columns are smallints and the rest are varchars. There are more columns, but they are irrelevant to this question.

My goal is to produce address labels that we can stick onto envelopes and send a newsletter to family members. At an address can have a single family member, or a whole family: father + mother + kid + kid for example. Not every person is a member (for one, you need to be older than 18). Members have an *IsMember* of 1, otherwise *IsMember* is 0. The code is a representation of the lineage of the person: children have longer codes than their parents; in-law spouses (who married into the family) have longer codes than the person who was in the family from birth.

The problem is getting the correct SQL Select query that produces the 7 columns (I don't need *IsMember*), but only produces 1 line (= 1 label) per *ADDRESS1*. And the *code* and *FullName* need to belong to the oldest person that was born into the family, not married into the family. In other words, I want the person on an address that has the shortest code.

My first idea was to write a simple query that would select all the columns. Then Order By the result based on the length() of *code*. And then finally run that through a Group By of the *ADDRESS1* column.

But you aren't allowed to use the Group By after the Order By. And the other way around doesn't produce the correct result: instead of returning the oldest original family member it returns a random member of that family.

The data could be something like:

```
+----+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| ID | code | FullName | ADDRESS1 | ADDRESS2 | ADDRESS3 | COUNTRY  | IsMember |
+----+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1  | A1   | Alex     | Main 10  | 1234 AB  | New York | USA      | 1        |
| 2  | A1.2 | Fred     | Longstr 1| 5757 GE  | London   | UK       | 1        |
| 3  | A1a  | Alexa    | Main 10  | 1234 AB  | New York | USA      | 1        |
| 4  | J2   | John     | 2nd Str 7| 1970 BV  | The Hague| NL       | 1        |
| 5  | J2a  | Janet    | 2nd Str 7| 1970 BV  | The Hague| NL       | 1        |
| 6  | J2.1 | Alfred   | 2nd Str 7| 1970 BV  | The Hague| NL       | 1        |
| 7  | J2.2 | Eric     | 2nd Str 7| 1970 BV  | The Hague| NL       | 0        |
| 8  | J3   | Donald   | ObraStr 8| 8582 UT  | Toronto  | CA       | 0        |
+----+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

And the expected result would be:

```
+----+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| ID | code | FullName | ADDRESS1 | ADDRESS2 | ADDRESS3 | COUNTRY  |
+----+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1  | A1   | Alex     | Main 10  | 1234 AB  | New York | USA      |
| 2  | A1.2 | Fred     | Longstr 1| 5757 GE  | London   | UK       |
| 4  | J2   | John     | 2nd Str 7| 1970 BV  | The Hague| NL       |
+----+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

In other words: we get only one result per *ADDRESS1* and the corresponding data on that line belongs to the person with the shortest *code*. So Alex instead of Alexa on Main 1, and John instead of Janet on 2nd Str 7.
Only lines with *IsMember* = 1 are taken into account.
The order of the lines in the end result is irrelevant to me.

So I first tried:

```
Select ID
, code
, FullName
, ADDRESS1
, ADDRESS2
, ADDRESS3
, COUNTRY
from `people`
Where IsMember = 1
Order by Length(code)
Group By ADDRESS1
;
```

But that gives an error.

So I switched to try to nest SQL code, like

```
SELECT id
, code
, FullName
, ADDRESS1
, ADDRESS2
, ADDRESS3
, COUNTRY
from (
  SELECT id
  , code
  , FullName
  , ADDRESS1
  , ADDRESS2
  , ADDRESS3
  , COUNTRY
  from `people`
  where IsMember = 1
) as tempvar
order by length(code)
;
```

but that also fails when I try to add in the Group By somewhere.

When I try

```
SELECT id
, code
, FullName
, ADDRESS1
, ADDRESS2
, ADDRESS3
, COUNTRY
from (
  SELECT id
  , code
  , FullName
  , ADDRESS1
  , ADDRESS2
  , ADDRESS3
  , COUNTRY
  from `people`
  where IsMember = 1
  order by length(code)
) as tempvar
group by ADDRESS1
;
```

then the ordering is lost, and the group comes up with a random member in the family again.

Can someone help me out here?

-Edited to add examples-

Comment: What do you expect the result to look like?

Comment: `ORDER BY`comes after `GROUP BY`

Comment: sample input and output data please

Comment: Thanks @dougp for the formatting. I have added an example database and a result that would suit me.

Comment: GROUP BY is used for aggregations but you don’t use any aggregation function. Why?

Comment: Hi @nbk, I know that ORDER BY comes after GROUP BY, but that gives the wrong result for me. If I do a GROUP BY first, then I do get unique _ADDRESS1_, but then either I get a random line with that _ADDRESS1_ (not with the shortest _code_), or when I add the rest of the data, it adds them all (while I only want 1 line for each _ADDRESS1_).

Comment: I was first using DISTINCT to find the unique _ADDRESS1_, @FrankHeikens. Then I read that a GROUP BY was similar. The problem with DISTINCT is that it works on the whole SELECT, not on just the _ADDRESS1_.
Anything else is fine, I was trying to get a list of unique _ADDRESS1_.

Comment: @StarTroll Next time please post your input as DDL (example in my answer) as this makes it easier for a potential answerer to get started.  Also tag the question with the RDBMS you are using to enable the potential answerer to work in the correct environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code and here I have used "order by" clause

```
SELECT ID, code, FullName, ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2, ADDRESS3, COUNTRY
FROM (
  SELECT ID, code, FullName, ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2, ADDRESS3, COUNTRY,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ADDRESS1 ORDER BY LENGTH(code)) AS rn
  FROM people
  WHERE IsMember = 1
) AS tempvar
WHERE rn = 1;
```

I hope this could help you!!

Comment: Hi @Jack D, it looks like this indeed does exactly what I what, thanks a million!
Of course.... this means that I will be spending the coming days researching "Row_Number() over" and "Partition by".... :D

Answer (score 0):

The code below will present the code of minimum length for the address.  I use the full address instead of `ADDRESS1` because if you have people at these two addresses...

Main 10
1234 AB
New York
USA

Main 10
5678 CD
Chicago
USA

...you probably don't want all of the mail going to the first address.

This solution is written for SQL Server.  Your mileage may vary.

```
with people (
  ID
  , code
  , FullName
  , ADDRESS1
  , ADDRESS2
  , ADDRESS3
  , COUNTRY 
  , IsMember
) as (
  select *
  from (
    values 
      (1 , 'A1'  , 'Alex'  , 'Main 10'  , '1234 AB', 'New York' , 'USA', 1)
    , (2 , 'A1.2', 'Fred'  , 'Longstr 1', '5757 GE', 'London'   , 'UK' , 1)
    , (3 , 'A1a' , 'Alexa' , 'Main 10'  , '1234 AB', 'New York' , 'USA', 1)
    , (4 , 'J2'  , 'John'  , '2nd Str 7', '1970 BV', 'The Hague', 'NL' , 1)
    , (5 , 'J2a' , 'Janet' , '2nd Str 7', '1970 BV', 'The Hague', 'NL' , 1)
    , (6 , 'J2.1', 'Alfred', '2nd Str 7', '1970 BV', 'The Hague', 'NL' , 1)
    , (7 , 'J2.2', 'Eric'  , '2nd Str 7', '1970 BV', 'The Hague', 'NL' , 0)
    , (8 , 'J3'  , 'Donald', 'ObraStr 8', '8582 UT', 'Toronto'  , 'CA' , 0)
  ) q (
      ID
    , code
    , FullName
    , ADDRESS1
    , ADDRESS2
    , ADDRESS3
    , COUNTRY 
    , IsMember
  )
),
a as (
  Select ID
  , code
  , FullName
  , ADDRESS1
  , ADDRESS2
  , ADDRESS3
  , COUNTRY
  , len(code) as codelen
  , min(len(code)) over (partition by ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2, ADDRESS3, COUNTRY) as mincodelen
  from people
  Where IsMember = 1
)

select *
from a
where codelen = mincodelen
order by ID
;
```